# YouTube API requires postMessage(). Why?

Tags: javascript, api, youtube

I've been trying to get the YouTube JS API's `stopVideo()` method to work for some time now.  Everyone says it's as simple as calling it on the iframe element, but the only way I was able to get it to work was via a method called `postMessage()` which I found on someone else's Stackoverflow post.

**The code:**

```
$('iframe').postMessage('{"event":"command","func":"stopVideo","args":""}', '*')
```

is what eventually got it working for me.  But still, I don't understand what I'm doing.  Can anyone explain this to me?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[From MDN postMessage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/window.postMessage)

> `window.postMessage` is a method for safely enabling cross-origin
>   communication. Normally, scripts on different pages are only allowed
>   to access each other if and only if the pages which executed them are
>   at locations with the same protocol (usually both http), port number
>   (80 being the default for http), and host (modulo document.domain
>   being set by both pages to the same value). window.postMessage
>   provides a controlled mechanism to circumvent this restriction in a
>   way which is secure when properly used.

So what it does is lets you get around the [same origin policy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Same_origin_policy_for_JavaScript) and talk to other domains. Only issue, not all browsers support it.

Comment: Interesting.  One thing to note is that the latest YouTube embed code uses iframes.

Comment: Thank you.  It seems to me that only IE 7 and below doesn't support it.  That's good enough for me!  Thanks!